# sql_ssms_loc.msi missing

Tags: sql, windows-installer

I'm trying to install sql management studio 2017, but I get an error every time "Click OK to try again, or enter an alternate path to a folder containing the installation package 'sql_ssms_loc.msi' in the box below". 
It referred me to this:

> "C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache{1B8CFC46-1F08-4DA7-9FEA-E1F523FBD67F}v14.0.17213.0\x64\".

But this source doesn't exist.

Comment: How are you invoking this install? Where did you download from and what is the name of the file you invoke?

Comment: From the official source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

You usually get this message when Windows thinks the product is already installed, and so it goes into maintenance mode, which tries to find the MSI file used for the original install. It appears that a previous install of SQL Management Studio has been attempted and perhaps failed, but the cached MSI files for that attempt have been uninstalled.

Because Windows thinks that this particular piece of Management Studio is already installed, The most likely fix would be to make sure it's not already installed, and if so then uninstall it.

Comment: how to manually uninstall it? It seems that the previous installation was not completed, but I don't see it in All programs.